# How to dynamically resize CSS button sprites (background image)?

Tags: css, background-image, image-resizing, centering, css-sprites

Using CSS, how can I make the button images `background: url();` scale down relative to the the parent div? The parent div is centered and set to scale according to viewport width `vw`.

Any ideas?

EDIT
What's important here is scaling to the viewport width, not a parent div.

```css
   body {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  margin: 0px; 
  border: 0px black;
  padding: 0px;
  }

 #parent {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 80vw;
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);     
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;    
     }

  a{
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;    
  }  

            #alpha a{                        
  width: 200px;   
  background: url("https://gordonlesti.com/media/post/css-background-transitions-with-image-sprites/sprite.png") 0 0;       
     } 
    
     #alpha a:hover {                       
  width: 200px;   
  background: url("https://gordonlesti.com/media/post/css-background-transitions-with-image-sprites/sprite.png") 200px 0;            
     }            

            #beta a{                       
  width: 200px;   
  background: url("https://gordonlesti.com/media/post/css-background-transitions-with-image-sprites/sprite.png") 0 0;      
        } 

       #beta a:hover {           
  width: 200px;   
  background: url("https://gordonlesti.com/media/post/css-background-transitions-with-image-sprites/sprite.png") 200px 0;                
     }
```

```html
<div id=parent> 

    <div id="alpha"><a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="beta"><a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: background-size:100% 100% ---> assuming your buttons are 100% of the width and height of the parent ... otherwise use appropriate percentage values

Comment: Where are your buttons?

Comment: The pink circles are my test buttons. They are sprites that turn green on hover. The grey box behind them are the parent container.

Comment: background-size:100% has not worked for me

Comment: Thanks David for the tip. Setting background-size did help along with finally adding vw. The solution is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the background-size to set this, as your images are as tall as the buttons but twice the width, you can use '  background-size:200% 100%;'

and then to "switch" the image to the next one you can change the position to be 100%

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  margin: 0px; 
  border: 0px black;
  padding: 0px;
  }

 #parent {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 80vw;
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);     
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;    
     }

  a{
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;    
  }  

            #alpha a{                        
  width: 100px;   

  background: url("https://gordonlesti.com/media/post/css-background-transitions-with-image-sprites/sprite.png") 0 0;
            background-size:200% 100%;
 
     } 
    
     #alpha a:hover {                       
  width: 100px;   
 
  background: url("https://gordonlesti.com/media/post/css-background-transitions-with-image-sprites/sprite.png") 100% 0;      
       background-size:200% 100%;
     }            

            #beta a{                       
  width: 100px;   
   
  background: url("https://gordonlesti.com/media/post/css-background-transitions-with-image-sprites/sprite.png")0 0;
      background-size: 200% 100%;

        } 

       #beta a:hover {           
  width: 100px;

  background: url("https://gordonlesti.com/media/post/css-background-transitions-with-image-sprites/sprite.png") 100% 0; 
        background-size:200% 100%;
       
     }
```

```html
<div id=parent> 

    <div id="alpha"><a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="beta"><a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: @logoologist I believe so as long as the sprite is the same ratio of height to width. Or if it's not if you change the %'s to match the new ratio.

Comment: This way, of course, the pink buttons are no longer both pink. Pink represents the desired "unhovered" state, while aqua represents the desired hover state.

Comment: @logoologist That's simply because I changed the un hovered state of beta to show it could be done either way. I've changed back in the example now

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing that. What if I want the images to scale down according to the parent div's with? Does that this solution still work? Ultimately, I want the images to be able to scale down from their max size upon resizing the browser window.

Comment: @logoologist yes, I've made a jsfiddle that will change with the height of the browser. https://jsfiddle.net/jfe4wthm/ you can see the sprites work fine

Comment: The final part of the problem is that the images won't scale down upon resizing the browser window. I tried both vh and vw for the parent div, and either way the div resizes relative to the browser window but the images don't resize.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. What code should I change to enable resizing to width?

Comment: @logoologist in the example code above, you have hardcoded the with and height of the A tag to 100px, if you want this to scale you will need to use a % value.

Comment: would this work? #alpha, #beta{
     height:100% width: 100%
    }

Comment: With a % in the A tag the buttons become horizontally squeezed and they're not scaling down within the parent container's width from what I'm seeing.

Comment: @logoologist I feel like this discussion is outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: Essentially, I want the button images to scale upon resizing of the window, but I want to maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Dale, I really appreciate your help with this. My latest question I think gets at the heart of the problem I've been trying to solve.

Comment: Finally, maintaining the aspect ratio simply required changing the button's ratio to a vw like:  height: 10vw; width: 10vw;. Sorry Dale if my description of the problem wasn't clear. I edited the question now for more clarity. The solution can be seen here: http://dabblet.com/gist/40738a1ef8ce3a51a2511c8570916391